# Correct normalty preconditions for the t-Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, normality-assumption

Lately, I have had several data sets at hand that I want to use to study the effect of a treatment. The data is in the form of:

\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Participant} \quad & \text{value before} \quad & \text{value after} \quad & \text{difference} \quad \\
\hline
1 & 64 & 62 &2 \\
2 & 58 & 53 & 5 \\
\vdots & & & \\
\hline
\end{array}

([best attempt to display a table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables))

I assume the paired t-test to be a good test to decide if the difference in values before and after the treatment are significant. However, I'm unsure about the pre-conditions of this test.
Half of the sources I find state that I need to check for normality of the distribution of values before and after the test (this is given in my sample).
The other half states that I need to check the normality of the *difference* of the values (this is not given in my sample).

Which (if not both?) of the checks is truly necessary and why?

Comment: I think you can use MathJax t create arrays which serve the same function as your table. This is explained in one of the answers to the post you link to.

Comment: It is the differences which are relevant (the test is often referred to as the one-sample t-test which gives you a clue). Having said that moderate departures from normality ar eunlikely to affect much.

Comment: thanks @mdewey, didn't scroll down long enough... The long headers where a bit tricky, but it looks nice now. Also thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a paired t-test, you should look for normality in the differences.  A paired t-test uses the differences to compute the test statistic, so the differences are all that matter, not the original data.  See Bland's "Introduction to Medical Statistics" for more.

Comment: Thanks @demetri-pananos, that book helped. I think I understand now why the differences are of interest and why there is the assumption that the difference is normally distributed. One last thing: I can test for this normality assumption by testing my sample differences because if the difference follows a normal distribution in the population, then I would also assume that my sample should follow a normal distribution, correct?

Comment: @nirolo Yea, sure

Comment: In reality the Gauss-Markov theorem specifies that the model errors are normally distributed, but this would imply normality of the differences.